# VB.net 2008 document finding

Tags: vb.net, document

i am using VB. net 2008. I am having a hard time using this code:

("L:\SWPPP\SWPPPBookMerge.doc")

what is the shortest method that the system will search for the document without placing the document address.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this?

```
Dim dir = New DirectoryInfo("L:\SWPPP\")
Dim files As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles("*.doc")
For Each file As FileInfo In files
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName)
Next
```